# Return type of SQLPredicate on HazlecastMap

Tags: java, hazelcast

Does a SQLPredicate on a hazelcast map return a Set (as per the documentation) or an arraylist?  I am using v3.2.4 client and server.  The client connects to the server and makes the following call (this worked on a single server but now that I am using the client, I'm not sure what's causing the problem).

```
Predicate testPredicate = equal("testGroupID", 101);  //testGroupID is attribute 
Set<testObj> testInstances = (Set<testObj>)testMap.values(testPredicate);
```

I am getting the following exception on the second line:

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `SQLPredicate` but `Predicates.equal`. However, that's a side point. The main point is the [API](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#values(com.hazelcast.query.Predicate)):

```
Collection<V> values(Predicate predicate)
```

So, no mention of `values()` returning a `Set`, and indeed you didn't get a `Set`.

Finally, since a map can legally have duplicate values, you would probably not *want* a `Set` returned.

Comment: thanks William - I think I need to slow down and pay attention